# Better quality PNG transparency with PHP

Tags: php, image, merge, png

I have a code that looks like this:

```
<?php
$imgl = "test/white.png";
$img2 = "test/1.png";

$dest = imagecreatefrompng($imgl);
$src = imagecreatefrompng($img2);
imagecolortransparent($src, imagecolorat($src, 0, 0));
imagecolortransparent($dest, imagecolorat($dest, 0, 0));

$src_x = imagesx($src);
$src_y = imagesy($src);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, 100);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

This code merges images together, while keeping their transparency. However, this code keeps the transparency of the images very low quality and the edges look very rough. I was wondering, is there a way that I can still keep the transparency of the images, but with better quality? I still want this script to complete the same function, however.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're outputting the image as a GIF, instead of a PNG. Try `imagepng()` instead of `imagegif()`.

```
imagepng($dest);
```

Comment: Hmm, I've tried that, but it makes all of the black outlines/shapes on the image transparent as well.

Answer (score 0):

GIFs only have a 1-bit alpha channel, meaning that it is unable to represent partial transparency. Each pixel is either fully transparent or fully opaque. This is the first potential issue with your code.

The other one is that `imagecolortransparent()` sets a single color to be interpreted as transparent. This means that only pixels with *exactly* that color will be transparent. You may need to implement actual true-color per-pixel transparency yourself if you need smooth transitions.